# Resolving Nested macro linking error

Tags: c, macros, linker

I am getting a linking error because a function is declared in a .h file but its definition is commented. 
Below is the linking error:
          --- Linking Error --- 
          Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol clk_SetHMSSAPMFreqPlan (referred 
          from VVDRV_clk_glue.o).

Now, the file where the function is being called has multiple nested if blocks like below:

```
 #if defined(COMPILING_APPS_PROC) || defined(COMPILING_SPM_PROC)
 #ifndef AXF_BUILD
    eClkResult clk_SetFreqPlan(eClockFrequencyType eFreqPlan, uint32 eSubsystemLists) {
      ----some code----
        #if defined(COMPILING_APPS_PROC) && !defined(AXF_BUILD)
            clk_SetHMSSAPMFreqPlan(0, eFreqPlan); /* This function is giving a linking error */
        #endif
 #endif /*AXF_BUILD*/
 #endif /*COMPILING_APPS_PROC*/
```

To get over the linking error, on top of the file I am declaring the macro:
            #ifndef AXF_BUILD
            #define AXF_BUILD 1
            #endif

Because the other macro COMPILING_APPS_PROC has to be kept defined, I cannot change it.

Since, AXF_BUILD is now defined, I am expecting the function clk_SetHMSSAPMFreqPlan(0, eFreqPlan) will not be compiled and compilation should be clean. But, I am still getting the same linking error. What might be the reason?

Comment: You really need to show more code, and include the exact linking error, for a start.

Comment: Added more code and also the linking error